# Jenkins installation on Ubuntu using Vagrant - NO HTTP access

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jenkins, vagrant, devops

I've been trying to install Jenkins on ubuntu using Vagrant. Even though I am not getting any errors along the way I am not able to open http://localhost:8080

Here's my steps:

1. Install Vagrant and Virtual Box on MAC
2. Create a folder for the vagrant
3. vagrant init bento/ubuntu-16.04
4. nano Vagrantfile - delete the hasztag from the port forwarding to 8080
5. Vagrant up
6. Vagrant ssh

Install git:

1. Sudo apt-get install git
2. Git --version

Installing Java:

1. sudo apt update
2. Sudo apt-get upgrade
3. sudo apt install default-jdk
4. sudo apt install default-jre

Install Jenkins:

1. wget -q -O - http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian/jenkins-ci.org.key | sudo apt-key add -
2. sudo sh -c 'echo deb http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian binary/ > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list'
3. sudo apt-get install -y jenkins --allow-unauthenticated
4. To check the password: vi /var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log
5. To start Jenkins: systemctl start jenkins
   systemctl status jenkins

When I start the jenkins server I can do telnet 127.0.0.1 8080 but when I turn it off it doesn't work. Any idea why I cannot access GUI using the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Try in ubuntu to do "curl http://localhost:8080" , if response is not some error code page, like 4xx/5xx, check firewall and allow traffic on port 8080. Therefore try to access Jenkins from Host Machine.

Comment: Thanks. I have the same issue with Prometheus running inside the Vagrant. Output from ubuntu inside the vagrant: vagrant@vagrant:~/prometheus-course$ curl http://localhost:9090
<a href="/graph">Found</a>.

Output from my mac: curl http://localhost:9090
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9090: Connection refused

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have a service running on port 8080 on your guest machine.